# Как добавить переменное количество виджетов в QScrollArea?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qlayout, qscrollarea

Имеется виджет, где центральный виджет это QScrollArea. 
Также имеется другой виджет, который будет вставляться в первый **`n`**-ое кол-во раз.

Как сделать так, чтобы виджеты внутри области прокрутки прокручивались, а не находились вместе(пробовал через `Layout`'ы).

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import Qt


class ExampleWidget(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(ExampleWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUi()
        
    def initUi(self):
        self.mainLayout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        self.label_1 = Qt.QLabel('One')
        self.label_2 = Qt.QLabel('Two')
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)        
        

class ScrollWidget(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
    super(ScrollWidget, self).__init__(parent)
    self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.area = Qt.QScrollArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.area)
    
    def addWidget(self):
        #  How to add widget with scrolling into area?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import Qt

class ExampleWidget(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ExampleWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.mainLayout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        self.label_1 = Qt.QLabel('One')
        self.label_2 = Qt.QLabel('Two')
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)        


class ScrollWidget(Qt.QWidget):      
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ScrollWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.layoutV = Qt.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.area = Qt.QScrollArea(self)
        #self.setCentralWidget(self.area)       # setCentralWidget <- QMainWindow
        self.area.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = Qt.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(Qt.QRect(0, 0, 200, 100))

        self.layoutH = Qt.QHBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout = Qt.QGridLayout()
        self.layoutH.addLayout(self.gridLayout)

        self.area.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.add_button = Qt.QPushButton("Add Widget")
        self.layoutV.addWidget(self.area)
        self.layoutV.addWidget(self.add_button)
        self.add_button.clicked.connect(self.addWidget)

        self.widget = ExampleWidget()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.widget)
        self.setGeometry(700, 200, 200, 100)        

    def addWidget(self):
        #  Как добавить виджет с прокруткой в ​​область?
        self.widget = ExampleWidget()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = ScrollWidget()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]